# Redirect URL with htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite

A third party plugin returns to an incorrect URL from a call to save a change.

The URL is `/admin/?page=configure/admin/`. The correct return should be to `/lists/admin/?page=configure`. My attempt to write a redirect failed with a 500 server error.

```
    RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/admin/(.*)$ $1/lists/admin/$2 [NC,L]
```

How can I correct this code?

Comment: And mod_rewrite is enabled? Note that RewriteEngine on and RewriteRule should be on two separate lines.

Comment: They were, but when I uploaded the question, they were combined. I have corrected the question.

Comment: I think those are supposed to be `(.*)` instead of `(.)`

Comment: That's true (.*). The * also disappeard in the post. It is present in the source of the question when I edit it. How do I get the * to print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^lists
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?admin/(.*)$ $1lists/admin/$2 [QSA,L]
```

If you want to match a different folder to redirect to admin you will have to declare it literally as a pattern like `^(.*)?/admin` would also match `lists/admin` and cause a loop.